# Auto increment EC2 instance Name

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have seen many questions on Stackoverflow asking if there is a way to auto-increment instance names. For example:

```
foo1
foo2
fooN
```

I am trying to see if there is a way of doing this in Powershell. I am using AutoLaunchConfiguration/ASG to spin up the instances. Is there a programmatic way of auto-incrementing instance ways? Every resource I have seen so far says it's possible but no on provides a means of doing this. Here are some of the resources I am looking at:

- [Method to provide incremental name to ec2 instances created using auto scaling group in aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615049/method-to-provide-incremental-name-to-ec2-instances-created-using-auto-scaling-g)
- [How to create variable number of EC2 instance resources in Cloudformation template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251934/how-to-create-variable-number-of-ec2-instance-resources-in-cloudformation-templa)

Does anyone have a working example of doing this using AutoLaunchConfiguration and ASG? If so, can you please provide a link/article that can provide me with this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing is to decide **what is meant by "auto-incrementing"**.

For example, if these instances already exist:

- `foo1`
- `foo2`

then obviously the next instance would be `foo3`.

But let's say that an instance has previously been terminated because load reduced, and the currently-running instances are:

- `foo1`
- `foo3`

Then the question is whether the next instance should be `foo2` or `foo4`.

If the answer is `foo4`, then think of the situation where `foo4` is later terminated and another instance is launched. Should it be `foo4` or `foo5` (since there was previously a `foo4`).

It really boils down to **determining *why* you want an auto-incremented name**.

The reasons are typically:

- The need for a **unique name**
- The need for a **human-friendly name**
- The need for a hint as to the **order in which instances where launched**

If the need is for a **unique name**, then the **Instance ID** can fulfil this need perfectly, without needing an additional name.

Let's assume you want to go with a human-friendly name and you are okay to re-use names that were previously used (eg if `foo1` and `foo3` exists, then use `foo2` next). In such a case, you would need something that logically **inspects the existing instances and finds the first unused number**.

If, on the other hand, you never wanted to re-use names, then you would need **some place to store the 'current' number** so that it can be incremented for the next instance.

Then, finally, comes the question of **how to assign the auto-incremented name** (which is your original question, but the above is also very important to understand first). My recommendation would be:

- Add some code to each instance that is triggered through the **User Data** so that it will run when the instance is launched (eg PowerShell)
- The code will **inspect the existing instances with [`describe-instances`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) or the place where the count is kept**, then assign itself the next number
- The code can then call [`create-tags`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html) on itself, adding a `Name` tag with the appropriate name